# Spring banner is not printed within log

Tags: spring-boot, logging, banner, tomcat9

Within my Spring Boot application (`loglevel=DEBUG`) I do log against `slf4j`, `jcl` (commons logging), `log4j` and `jul` (java util logging). I do use following:

- log4j-to-slf4j.jar
- slf4j-log4j12.jar
- commons-logging.jar
- log4j.jar
- jul-to-slf4j.jar

Running it on Tomcat (juli) it doesnt print the Spring Boot bannner.

We are using Tomcat with a **Logging Bridge**. This Logging Bridge contains a LoggingListener (that implments the org.apache.catalina.LifecycleListener) and does redirect every Log from System.out and System.err.

```
systemOut = System.out;
systemErr = System.err;

System.setOut(new PrintStream(new LoggingOutputStream(Level.DEBUG, systemOut), true));
System.setErr(new PrintStream(new LoggingOutputStream(Level.WARN, systemErr), true));
```

The execution of this code snipped is based on a class attribute flag (private boolean redirectSystemLogs) which is always true - I tried to steer this flag from outside (tomcat clathpath) but didnt succeed. And still I would expect that with loglevel DEBUG I should be able to see the spring banner in the logs.

Comment: Check that the configuration property `spring.main.banner-mode`is not set in the `off` value.

Comment: There is none in the application properties. Do you think tomcat 9.0.30 has that implemented somewhere?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to tell it to print to the log file and not the console.  In your application.yml:

```
spring:
  main:
    banner-mode: log
```

https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/Banner.Mode.html